# Removing identifier with "unavailable sequence" from FASTA file

Tags: regex, perl, sequence, fasta

I'm new to perl and regex, but have used the guidance from this article to try to remove gene sequences in a FASTA file that have either "Sequence unavailable" or "No UTR is annotated..." for a given identifier:
https://www.biostars.org/p/127842/

Unfortunately, my perl script is not producing the desired results. The script is as follows:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$/="\n>";

while (<>) {

 s/>//g;

  my ($id, $seq) = split (/\n/, $_);

  print ">$_" if ((length $seq) > 10 && ($seq !~ "Sequence unavailable" or $seq !~ "No UTR is annotated for this transcript"));

}
```

The input file looks like this:

```
>AT1G02810|AT1G02810.1
CTGTGAGCCTATGGCATATGTACCACGTTAAGATTTAAGAAAATCTGGAATAAAAAATGC
AACTAGATATTATGTTATACAAATCTAGGCCAGAGTCGGTTGTTTTCGGACCGTTCTGCC
GTGAAACTGTGTTCCTTAACATTTTGATTTAACGTTTCCATATTTCTGACATTCCAATAA
ATTATTGATAACTAGTAATTAATTAAAACGGTTTACTCTGAACTCTGAAGTGTGTGAGGT
>AT1G04635|AT1G04635.1
Sequence unavailable
> ...
```

My script's output file is as follows:

```
>CTGTGAGCCTATGGCATATGTACCACGTTAAGATTTAAGAAAATCTGGAATAAAAAATGC
AACTAGATATTATGTTATACAAATCTAGGCCAGAGTCGGTTGTTTTCGGACCGTTCTGCC
GTGAAACTGTGTTCCTTAACATTTTGATTTAACGTTTCCATATTTCTGACATTCCAATAA
ATTATTGATAACTAGTAATTAATTAAAACGGTTTACTCTGAACTCTGAAGTGTGTGAGGT
> ...
```

However, my DESIRED output would be:

```
>AT1G02810|AT1G02810.1
CTGTGAGCCTATGGCATATGTACCACGTTAAGATTTAAGAAAATCTGGAATAAAAAATGC
AACTAGATATTATGTTATACAAATCTAGGCCAGAGTCGGTTGTTTTCGGACCGTTCTGCC
GTGAAACTGTGTTCCTTAACATTTTGATTTAACGTTTCCATATTTCTGACATTCCAATAA
ATTATTGATAACTAGTAATTAATTAAAACGGTTTACTCTGAACTCTGAAGTGTGTGAGGT
> ...
```

From my understanding, I hope this is a simple syntax error in my perl script... would appreciate any guidance provided on obtaining the desired result.

Comment: We cannot help you solve your problem if you don't post working code. I'm guessing you've pasted from a text editor, and it's truncated the long line.

Comment: Yes, you're right, just slipped my mind as I was copying the code. I've updated the original post with the correct line.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the root of your problem is your conditional expression:

```
print ">$_" if ((length $seq) > 10 && ($seq !~ "Sequence unavailable" or $seq !~ "No UTR is annotated for this transcript"));
```

In particular - because you have a negated "or" condition - the not-or will *always* be "true" because `$seq !~ "No UTR is annotated for this transcript"` will evaluate as true when you have "Sequence unavailable".

So decompose it - move the 'not' outside the brackets:

```
print ">$_" if ((length $seq) > 10 and not ($seq =~ /Sequence unavailable/ or $seq =~ /No UTR is annotated for this transcript/));
```

Or better still - break the conditions apart, and use a `next if` type construct to skip:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = "\n>";

while (<>) {

   my ( $id, $seq ) = split /\n/, ;

   next if $seq =~ m/Sequence unavailable/;
   next if $seq =~ m/No UTR is annotated for this transcript/;
   next unless length $seq > 10;
   print;

}
```

Which is hopefully clearer how the logic is operating?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the suggestions! I tried this line but am still getting the same output - it is still removing the IDs/gene names for EVERY record, not just those containing the strings of interest.